# webpack 2 - is there a way to do global public url replacement

Tags: webpack-2

There are few assets generated via webpack. The assets themself are pretty regular, application.js, application.css, images and so on. The point is that at runtime that assets should be hosted inside a specific server-side assembly and because of this, all the urls should be changed in this manner:

- `dist/application.js` **==>** `?path=content.application.js`
- `dist/application.css` **==>** `?path=content.application.css`

...and so on for every style/script/image in the output bundle.

I tried the `publicPath` option of output section, but it looks like this functionality is not so powerful. So if I do this:

```
output: {
    // ...
    publicPath: "?path=content."
},
```

When the result for root html is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="?path=content./application.js">/script>
<link href="?path=content./application.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
```

Which is not correct as it has additional `/` that I cannot get rid of.

It would be great if `publicPath` was a function that returns dynamic path for every resource:

```
output: {
    // ...
    publicPath: function(originalFile){
        return /* generate publicPath dynamically */
    }
},
```

...but it's not the case with webpack2. So is there any method to globally replace public urls for all the resources? Or maybe some loader that does this.